# Transform jsonl file to a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a jsonl file looking like this:

```
{"id": 1, "data": "this is text. Here I am", "label": [[0, 13, "label_1"], [14, 23, "label_2"]]}
{"id": 2, "data": "Hi. Hello", "label": [[0, 2, "label_3"], [3, 8, "label_4"]]}
```

`[0, 13, "label_1"]` means from character 0 to 13 of the sentence.

I would like to have this, Pandas Dataframe expected output:

```
data              label  
this is text.     label_1        
Here I am         label_2         
Hi.               label_3 
Hello             label_4
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Hi, this is a json line file not a json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_json("your_file.jsonl", lines=True).explode("label")
df["data"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["data"][x["label"][0] : x["label"][1] + 1], axis=1
)
df["label"] = df["label"].str[-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id            data    label
0   1  this is text.   label_1
0   1       Here I am  label_2
1   2             Hi.  label_3
1   2           Hello  label_4
```